# installing webmin/plesk/cpanel/directadmin on pc on which squid proxy is installed

Tags: squid, cpanel, plesk, webmin

I am very new to Squid proxy- what I am wondering is, can I set up a hosting control panel like Cpanel/Webmin/Plesk/Directadmin, on the same box that also has squid proxy installed in it?

Will there be any problems due to both squid and the hosting control panel being installed on the same machine? Or is there some workaround to do this properly(ie set up hosting control panel and squid proxy on same machine?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Squids default port seems to be [`3129`](http://firewall.at/support/squid/Users-Guide/x505.html). If you run your administrative web application on Apache, it will use the default HTTP port `80`. So that would cover my main concern regarding conflicts.

Other than that, I don't see what could cause additional problems. But, then again, I never really used any of the administrative web applications you mention.